# strong name assembly - having to change thousands of assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/create-and-use-strong-named-assemblies

> A strong-named assembly can only use types from other strong-named assemblies. Otherwise, the integrity of the strong-named assembly would be compromised.

This is an issue because I would need to change all my thousands of assemblies, from weakly-named to strongly-named. This would take a long time, is there any way around this.

My use case:

I am building an application which will allow users to write C#, and execute it. I am doing this through an application domain. The application domain will compile the user code, in a partially trusted assembly. The user will be able to call a utilities assembly library. This utilities library, will be fully-trusted, and hence must be strongly named. This utilities library must be able to access the thousands of assemblies. The only way to do that now, is by changing all the assemblies to be strongly-named. which means I would need to add a AssemblyKeyFile attribute to each one.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right strongly typed assembly can not have weakly-named assemblies in the reference.

There is a cool nuget package which signs unsigned libraries in the references:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/strongnamer